# TypeError: Cannot read property 'bulkDelete' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I don't know what the problem is, I always get an error message when I execute the command: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bulkDelete' of undefined

I'm working with discord.js

### My Code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'clear',
    async execute(message, args) {
       
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("-")
        if (isNaN(args[0])) return message.channel.send("-")

        if (args[0] > 100) return message.channel.send("-")
        if (args[0] < 1) return message.channel.send

        await message.channel.messages.fetch({Limit: args[0]}).then(message =>{
            message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);

        });

    }
}
```

Comment: So you'll have to debug and figure out why `message.channel` is undefined

Comment: Probably the `message` parameter in the `.then()` function should be `messages`.

Comment: Message and Messages everywhere, as mentioned above, you need to debug to know what is the value of `message` in `then`, but I'd advise you to do some renaming to differentiate between things

Comment: There are two different variables named `message`.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what `bulkDelete` is try to check if it exists like:

```
if (message?.channel?.bulkDelete) {
  message.channel.bulkDelete();
}
```

Comment: This will suppress the error bug not solve the root cause. BTW, did you notice that he never declared `messages`.

Comment: In addition, optional chaining is very new and not widely supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming that this is the Discord API that you're working with:

`channel.messages` is a [MessageManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageManager)

When you call `fetch` with anything other than a message ID, you're going to get a `Collection` back, rather than a single message.

Thus, what you call `message`, should really be called `messages` and you should interact with it as a set of messages, rather than a single one.